# Set a specific changed date for a node

Tags: 7, nodes

I am creating nodes programatically based on the feed from an external api. I have managed to create all nodes, assign field values and also set the `created` date. Now my problem is that I also need to set the `changed` date of each node to match the value returned from the feed. I have tried to set this value before saving the node without any success:

```
// $data contains the release information used to create and populate the node
$node = new stdClass();
$node->title = $data->Release->Title;
$node->type = 'release';
node_object_prepare($node);
$node->status = NODE_PUBLISHED;
$node->uid = 1;
$node->language = LANGUAGE_NONE;

// handle any field data - not really important
handleFields($node, $data);

// submit the node
$node = node_submit($node);

$node->created = strtotime($data->Release->PublishDate);
// here I'm trying to set the changed value for the node
$node->changed = strtotime($data->Release->LastChangeDate);

// finally save the node
node_save($node);
```

Would be nice if anyone have a solution to this problem. Perhaps I can make a raw query against the database in order to update the `changed` date of the node?
The reason I need to set this value is because later on it will be used to compare against the modification date of a release in the feed so I can decide if the node needs to be updated or not. I know I could use a custom field for this purpose, storing the releases modification time and then compare against this value instead of the changed column in the node table.

Comment: Do you get any error, using that code? Drupal itself uses `$node->changed`, so the problem is not surely using that instead of something else.

Comment: @kiamlaluno - Nope I don't get any error. It just seems like drupal is not taking this custom value into account when saving the node. I know that drupal is using the `changed` column, but I don't understand why I may set the `created` but not the `changed` date? Not really sure what you mean by "so the problem is not surely using that instead of something else"? The reason I need to set the modification date is so that I later on can compare it against the modification date from the feed and decide if I need to update the node or not. I know this can be solved by using a separate field.

Comment: As side note, you can avoid calling `node_submit()`, since it just sets `$node->uid` and `$node->created`, which is something your code already does.

Comment: I mean that using `$node->created` is correct; it's not that you need to use, for example, `$node->timestamp` instead of `$node->created`. As for not using the value you set for `$node->created`, that could depend from what other modules do. It could be a module is changing its value. For sure, Drupal core sets `$node->created`, so setting it is correct.

Comment: @kiamlaluno - The problem is **not** the `created` date - I can set this without any problems as long as I do so **after** calling `node_submit()`. The problem is the `changed` date which I'm not able to set at the moment.

Comment: I meant `$node->changed`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code you are using doesn't work as expected because you first set `$node->changed` and then call [`node_save()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_save/7.x), which  sets `$node->changed` to `REQUEST_TIME` using the following code.

```php
// Set the timestamp fields.
if (empty($node->created)) {
  $node->created = REQUEST_TIME;
}
// The changed timestamp is always updated for bookkeeping purposes,
// for example: revisions, searching, etc.
$node->changed = REQUEST_TIME;

$node->timestamp = REQUEST_TIME;
$update_node = TRUE;

// Let modules modify the node before it is saved to the database.
module_invoke_all('node_presave', $node);
module_invoke_all('entity_presave', $node, 'node');
```

If you want to set `$node->changed`, you would need to implement [`hook_node_presave()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7.x), which is invoked right after `node_save()`. For example, with the code you show, I would add the following line.

```php
$node->release_change_date = strtotime($data->Release->LastChangeDate);
```

In `hook_node_presave()`, you would then use the following code.

```php
$node->changed = $node->release_change_date
```

Comment: I think this is exactly what I'm looking for =)

Comment: I would expect that Drupal first checks `$node->changed` is set, before setting it itself, as it does with `$node->created`. I find strange the decision of verifying a value is already set, but not doing the same for the other value.

Comment: Yes that was what I was thinking. But for some reason it does not so I will try to implement `hook_node_presave()` to store the modification date correctly.

Comment: This works as expected

Comment: "I would expect that Drupal first checks `$node->changed` is set" - The problem there is that a loaded node arrives with `$node->changed` already set. If the changed date was only set when there was no changed date set, the changed date would not change after node creation.

Comment: @KingAndy I don't see how a newly created node has already `$node->changed` set.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Newly created nodes don't. Nodes loaded by node_load() do, though! So for example when doing `$node = node_load($nid); $node->title = 'New title'; node_save($node);` the $node object will have a `changed` property already. If node_save only set `changed` when it was unset, it would retain the changed date from the previous save.

Comment: Of course Drupal could easily handle this by presenting the previous changed date in `$node->last_changed` or something instead of `changed`, but it doesn't. *shrug*

Comment: @KingAndy The problem I see is that `node_save()` doesn't allow a module to set the *changed* property, but it preserves other node properties a module could set. It's a lack of symmetry that forces developers to set that property directly in the database, when it should be preferable not to access the database for that.

Answer (score 0):

For drupal 7:

```
$update_node = node_load($nid_to_change);
$update_node->changed = $timestamp_in_unix_form;
drupal_write_record('node', $update_node, 'nid');
```

This is very dumb routine; it's bypassing a lot of error checking in node_save().   It expects a complete, intact node. so it's up to you to make sure the node integrity is good.  Otherwise you **risk corrupting your database.**